# Replacement of an encoder with strobe/CS line by a standard SSI encoder

Tags: protocol, rotary-encoder

The encoder is operated by a Beckhoff KL5001 unit, part of a larger control system with few documentation available. The strobe/CS signal is generated elsewhere in the system. I am wondering what would happen if I replaced the encoder by a standard SSI one. The KL5001 would not notice I guess. Could there be other implications? What is the purpose of the CS line anyhow? I understand that the readout is triggered by the clock signal train,or am I wrong?

Comment: CS - Chip Select - is usually used, when more units (same or different) share other Input and/or output and/or address lines. If CS is active for current unit, the unit should normally work as expected (read data, write data, use address lines etc.etc), but if CS is NOT active, the unit should ignore all its inputs and have all outputs in Hi-Z 3state - (high resistance, not low, not high, effectivelly disconnected). If unit does not react to CS in this way, it may even physically damage other parts (or itself). Which is problem if there are other connected units, or extendability is wanted.

Comment: There is just one encoder on the line. From what you said CS is not needed in that case. Moreover there is no reason for the encoder not to react. I think it was just a question of (non-)availabilty of certain encoders at the time of the fabrication of the system. Thenk you for your comment.